# How to do replicate Window's subst command in Python?

Tags: python, windows, mapped-drive, subst

I am trying to map a virtual drive on my windows setup one of the tools I am using does not like the spaces in the filenames.

On the command line, I would do the following

```
subst l: "c:\Program Files\Complier\version 6.0\bin"
```

I tried to replicate the functionality in Python without any success. I started using `os.execl()` to execute the `subst` command directly, but that reported an invalid parameter error.

Some of the other solutions on SO suggest using the Win32API directly.

By the way, I am using Python 2.7.3 on Windows.

Comment: May be `subprocess` module can help. Try using `subprocess.call()` for this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the Windows API directly. Note that you need to pass unicode strings here, or you could set argtypes on the function to get type-safe behaviour.

```
from ctypes import windll, c_int, c_wchar_p
DefineDosDevice = windll.kernel32.DefineDosDeviceW
DefineDosDevice.argtypes = [ c_int, c_wchar_p, c_wchar_p ]

# Create a subst. Check the return for non-zero to mean success
if DefineDosDevice(0, "T:", "C:\\Temp") == 0:
    raise RuntimeError("Subst failed")

# Delete the subst.
if DefineDosDevice(2, "T:", "C:\\Temp") == 0:
    raise RuntimeError("Couldn't remove subst")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using [`popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) and quoting the arguments correctly. You can also try the truncated path `C:\Progra~1`.